# Ansi escape code chart for CMD prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, prompt

How to find the command prompt ANSI escape code for the right-angle-quote `»`? (`&raquo;` [in html](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_r.asp)) I'd like to use this symbol for my CMD prompt shell instead of the default angle bracket `>`*

While the impetus for asking is seeking a single character, it would be good to have a general answer for looking up any character.

There are many [helpful](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html) [pages](https://conemu.github.io/en/AnsiEscapeCodes.html) for setting colours and controlling character position but I haven't found any that explain how to use ANSI symbols in general.

* *(Inadvertent copy-paste into a prompt which includes `>` is interpreted as *redirect output to file*, which can have unpleasant results.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hahaha! I was way over thinking the problem. The codes are not needed, just paste the character as is into the `set prompt` string. Or if typing it out use the sequence shown in [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1681919/16966)

So `set prompt=CMD$S$P$_»$S` result:

```
CMD C:\Users\Matt
»
```

And a more complicated version with colours:

```
rem Allow (some) Unicode (https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)
chcp 65001

set prompt=
$E[m$E[32mCMD$E\$S$E[92m$P$E[90m$_$E[90m»$E[m$S$E]9;12$E\`
```

[image: screenshot]

Also I learned that ANSI is actually an ill-defined term that could mean any of several things, but in this context the practical definition is *Windows code page 1252*; see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) for explanation and a chart that can be copied from.

On my system setting the code page to Unicode first with `chcp 65001` is needed in batch files but not when when setting the prompt interactively, where chcp remains at the default of `437`. I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML link listed `raquo` with the hex code of `BB`.

To enter this character in (almost) any application on Windows:

- Press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
- Press the <kbd>+</kbd> key in the numeric pad
- Press the <kbd>b</kbd> key twice
- Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

For more information see the article
[How to Use ALT Codes to Enter Special Characters & Symbols Using a Keyboard](https://altcodeunicode.com/how-to-use-alt-codes/).

Comment: But how to use that info for prompt? e.g. `set prompt=$p$e[xbb`, `set prompt=$p$e[0xbb` don't show the character.